# Cannot GET when setting up a server

Tags: node.js, express

I get the 'Cannot GET /' error when I try to open the server on port 5000. The problem is that my server is very simple and there should be no problem at all. Here's the code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.send('API is running...');
})
app.listen(5000, console.log('Server is running on port 5000'));
```

What could be the problem? The server is as simple as it can get.

Comment: Try: ```app.listen(5000, () => { console.log('Server is running on port 5000'); });```. PS: Do you see any error/s in the console?

Comment: works for me - what do you see?

Comment: Yes, I do see a 404 error

Comment: Are you accessing with this url (using a simple browser)? http://localhost:5000

Comment: Yes, I do access it with this url

Comment: Strange... Any error message when you run ```node [filename].js```?

Comment: I get "API is running..." - make sure you don't have something already running on port 5000.  Try changing to 5001

Comment: You have something else running on port 5000. You can change the port (8080) or kill the process using that port

Comment: Weird, when I run the script from the root folder using 'npm start' when the starting script is defined as "start" : "node backend/server.js" in package.json file, I get the error as mentioned in the original post, but when I run it using 'node [filename].js from inside my backend folder it works as intended

Comment: Maybe npm hide the error logs.

Comment: Anyway we have successfully found the error.. the port is alreay in use :)